# How to count songs from ipod Library including Duplicates

Tags: objective-c, ipod

I am trying to count the total songs from the ipod library.  Due to grouping any songs with same title will not be added to the array.

```
MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];    
NSArray *mySongs = [songsQuery collections];     
NSLog(@"%d", [mySongs count]);
```

Is there an alternative/better way? Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [songsQuery items] instead. That returns an NSArray with all the MPMediaItems the query contains.